# Variation on Stokes Theorem for Manifolds (2)

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, manifolds, closed-form

Let $\omega \in \Omega^0(\mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus\{0\})$ be a $0$-form such that $d\omega=0$. Is the following statement true:

For any compact, oriented, $0$-dimensional submanifold $M$ of $\mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus\{0\}$, we have $\displaystyle \int\limits_{M}j^*\omega = 0$ with $j:M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus\{0\}$ the inclusion map.

I was looking for a counterexample, more or less like the first example on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms. But I couldn't work it out exactly. How can a point be a boundary of something else (in order to apply Stokes)?

Comment: A closed $0$ form on a connected manifold is just a constant function. If you want to apply Stokes' theorem, you will want to have $M$, which is a finite number of points, you will want $M=\partial N$ for some connected compact submanifold $N$ of (orientability isn't a problem since $N$ is one dimensional). such an $N$ exists iff the number $M$ has even cardinality.

Comment: Okay, I see that I can take for example $M$ to be the point $(1,0)$ and the point $(2,0)$, then $N$ is the segment $[1,2]$. How can I find a constant function $\omega$ such that $\displaystyle \int\limits_{N}d\omega$ is not $0$ (and $d\omega=0$ from assumption)?

Comment: You won't find one, because your own hypothesis demands $d\omega=0$...

Comment: Okay, I thought the statement was false and was looking for a counterexample. Does there then exist one?

Comment: I don't understand what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Olivier suggests, if $f$ is a function (aka 0 form) on $\mathbb{R}^2-\{0\}$, and $df = 0$, then $f$ is a constant.

If you take a path in your space $\gamma$ from point $p$ to point $q$, then the boundary of this path is $q-p$ (i.e. the two endpoints, but with opposite signs).

Then we have

$$
0 = \int_\gamma df = \int_{b\gamma} f = f(q)-f(p) = 0
$$

which verifies Stoke's theorem.

It seems like you were intrigued by the fact that "$d\theta$" is closed but not exact.  In other words, it represents a nontrivial cohomology class in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^2-\{0\})$.

You seem to be looking for nontrivial cohomology in $H^0$, in other words functions which are closed but not exact.  The problem is, there are no "-1 forms", so $H^0$ is just defined as the space of closed forms.  In other words the locally constant functions.  In your case, since your space is connected, this is one dimensional:  just the constant functions.  If your space were disconnected (say a union of $n$ disjoint disks) then functions with $df=0$ can be a different constant on each  connected component.  So $H^0 \cong \mathbb{R}^n$ in this case.

Does this all make sense?  Another interesting example to go hunting for is a closed but not exact $2$-form on $\mathbb{R}^3-\{0\}$.  This should look more like the wikipedia example, if you are just looking to play around with similar things to test your understanding.